# How to create correct layout, to dsplay correctly in different screens?

Tags: android, testing, android-emulator, android-layout

i am developing Android application. In my application I have table layout for creating keyboard imitation. Each letter has own image, for displaying it. For wraping images row to current screen size I use "android:layout_height="wrap_content"" parameter, but it isn't resising images to fit the screen.

Here is cut of my layout:

```
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/keyBoard"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:stretchColumns="*">
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/action_buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5px">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_q" android:src="@drawable/q"
            android:padding="1px" android:layout_gravity="center" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_w" android:src="@drawable/w"
            android:padding="3px" android:layout_gravity="center" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_e" android:src="@drawable/e"
            android:padding="3px" android:layout_gravity="center" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_r" android:src="@drawable/r"
            android:padding="3px" android:layout_gravity="center" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_t" android:src="@drawable/t"
            android:padding="3px" android:layout_gravity="center" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_y" android:src="@drawable/y"
            android:padding="3px" android:layout_gravity="center" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_u" android:src="@drawable/u"
            android:padding="3px" android:layout_gravity="center" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_i" android:src="@drawable/i"
            android:padding="3px" android:layout_gravity="center" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_o" android:src="@drawable/o"
            android:padding="3px" android:layout_gravity="center" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_p" android:src="@drawable/p"
            android:padding="1px" android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/action_buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:paddingBottom="5px">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_a" android:src="@drawable/a"
            android:padding="5px" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_s" android:src="@drawable/s"
            android:padding="5px" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_d" android:src="@drawable/d"
            android:padding="5px" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_f" android:src="@drawable/f"
            android:padding="5px" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_g" android:src="@drawable/g"
            android:padding="5px" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_h" android:src="@drawable/h"
            android:padding="5px" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_j" android:src="@drawable/j"
            android:padding="5px" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_k" android:src="@drawable/k"
            android:padding="5px" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_l" android:src="@drawable/l"
            android:padding="5px" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/action_buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:paddingBottom="5px">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_z" android:src="@drawable/z"
            android:padding="5px" android:layout_gravity="center" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_x" android:src="@drawable/x"
            android:padding="5px" android:layout_gravity="center" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_c" android:src="@drawable/c"
            android:padding="5px" android:layout_gravity="center" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_v" android:src="@drawable/v"
            android:padding="5px" android:layout_gravity="center" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_b" android:src="@drawable/b"
            android:padding="5px" android:layout_gravity="center" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_n" android:src="@drawable/n"
            android:padding="5px" android:layout_gravity="center" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/let_m" android:src="@drawable/m"
            android:padding="5px" android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

What I am doing wrong? Because I am getting this result for some phones:
Port view:
[image]

And for Land view:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the images you are using are large in size. So,**wrap_content** doesn't gives you expected result.

You need to resize Alphabets image,
Ex. if current Image of Letter Q is 180 X 130 px then resize it to smaller size. Lets say 140 X 80 px.

Try it to your code. If you resize image and apply wrap_content then it will work ! Let me know if any problem exists. Thanks.

Comment: All alphabet images are 25x25 px. If i will resize images, then pressing them in app can be dificult

Comment: hey all alphabets are not visible thats problem due to its default size. If you need to overcome this then I strongly believe you need to resize it to smaller size. You can do 1 thing, create Images smaller than 25x25 put it in drawable-ldpi (for low res. devices) and put 25x25 , current images to mdpi folder for ( medium density devices).

Answer (score 0):

My way of creating layouts is providing width and height in 'dip' and not in 'px'.

And also you might have to use Relative Layout which would be handy